# Keep Value of Radio Button on Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My script:

```
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {

   var rowNum = $('#itemRows tr:last').attr("id");
   rowNum++;
  var row = '<tr id="'+rowNum+'"><td>'+rowNum+'</td><td><input type="text" name="nama[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td> <div class="radio"><label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="man" checked="checked" />Laki-laki</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="woman" />Perempuan</label></div></td><td><input type="text" name="weight[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="height[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="lla[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="lpgl[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="lpgg[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="tlk[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></td></tr>';
   jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
   frm.add_qty.value = '';
   frm.add_name.value = '';

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#'+rnum).remove();
  //susahnya ini kodong,....lamanya saya buat ini
  $('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
        $(this).children('td').first().html($(this).index()); 
        $(this).attr('id',$(this).index());
        var remo = 'removeRow('+$(this).index()+');';
        $(this).find('.btn-remo').attr("onclick",remo);

    });
}
```

html looks like this:

```
<form action="hasilObes.php" method="get" name="obes">
<table class="table table-striped" id="itemRows" cellpadding="3">
  <tr id="0">
    <th scope="col">No.</th>
    <th scope="col">Nama</th>
    <th scope="col">Gender</th>
    <th scope="col">BB</th>
    <th scope="col">TB</th>
    <th scope="col">LLA</th>
    <th scope="col">LPGI</th>
    <th scope="col">LPGG</th>
    <th scope="col">TLK</th>
    <th scope="col"><input class="btn btn-remo btn-info" onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Tambah" /></th>
  </tr>


</table>


<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="kalkulasi" />
</form>
```

If I click on button "tambah",..then new row will be added with default value of radio button (gender) is "man",...but if I then add new row,..value of radio (gender) previous or other row is gone,..now how to keep this value "man"/"woman" of other row when I add new row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because every time you add a row, you're adding two radio buttons with the same name, and therefore they're part of the same radio button group (all named "gender"). I would suggest that you simply change the name of the radio buttons so that each row is its own group.

In the `var row =` line of your code, change:

```
name="gender"
```

to:

```
name="row'+rowNum+'gender"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2KZCt/)**

This will produce radio button groups where the pair of radio buttons has the name, e.g.: row1gender, row2gender, row3gender, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Radio button name is same for every new row, now provided dynamic gender name `name="gender_'+rowNum+'"`

```
    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {

       var rowNum = $('#itemRows tr:last').attr("id");
       rowNum++;
      var row = '<tr id="'+rowNum+'"><td>'+rowNum+'</td><td><input type="text" name="nama[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td> <div class="radio"><label><input name="gender_'+rowNum+'" type="radio" value="man" checked="checked" />Laki-laki</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input name="gender_'+rowNum+'" type="radio" value="woman" />Perempuan</label></div></td><td><input type="text" name="weight[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="height[]" class="form-control" maxlength="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="lla[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="lpgl[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="lpgg[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="text" name="tlk[]" class="form-control" maxlength="4"></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></td></tr>';
       jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
     //  frm.add_qty.value = '';
      // frm.add_name.value = '';

    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
      jQuery('#'+rnum).remove();
      //susahnya ini kodong,....lamanya saya buat ini
      $('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
            $(this).children('td').first().html($(this).index()); 
            $(this).attr('id',$(this).index());
            var remo = 'removeRow('+$(this).index()+');';
            $(this).find('.btn-remo').attr("onclick",remo);

        });
    }
```